# Formulario imprime datos con PHP y MYSQL pero al actualizar ya no los muestra, pero están en la base de datos

Tags: php, mysql, formularios

les describo el problema.

He desarrollado un archivo pregunta.php?id=$pregunta_id que muestra la pregunta id correspondiente, en ese mismo archivo pregunta.php he creado un formulario que solo tiene un textaerea en el cual se debe responder dicha $pregunta_id.

Ese archivo tiene la validación del formulario, para guardar en la base de datos todo va bien.

En ese mismo archivo abajo de la pregunta pretendo mostrar las respuesta que los usuarios guarden en dicho formulario.

Las tablas de la base de datos están relacionadas (preguntas, respuestas y usuarios), por eso hice una función con la consulta INNER JOIN que mezcle la tabla preguntas con la de la respuesta y usuarios

En la terminal me muestra las respuestas de acuerdo a la pregunta_id significa que la consulta va bien.

luego en el archivo pregunta.php recorri el siguiente bucle:

```
      <?php
  $respuestas = selectRespuesta($db, $pregunta_id);
  if (!empty($respuestas)):
    while ($respuesta = mysqli_fetch_array($respuestas)):
      ?>
      <div class="card my-5">
        <div class="card-header">
          <h4>Respuesta</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title"><?php echo $respuesta['usuario']; ?></h5>  
          <p class="card-text"><?php echo $respuesta['respuesta']; ?></p>
        </div>
        </div>
      <?php
    endwhile;
  endif;
  ?>
```

Si yo escribo una respuesta el bucle funciona tambien y me muestra la respuesta justo abajo de la pregunta, con el nombre usuario que respondió.

el problema es que si yo quiero recargar la pagina me pide que si quiero reenviar el formulario, y me vuelve imprimir en pantalla la respuesta duplicada, y asi sucede si sigo recargando y enviando el formulario.

Pero que pasa si yo abando la pagina y veo otras paginas y regreso a la pregunta en la que respondí no me muestra las respuestas que hice anteriormente.

Descubrí que las muestra solo cuando vuelvo a escribir una respuesta y le doy enviar, es solo ahi cuando cuando me muestra las respuestas.

Resumiendo....

1. Cada vez que recargo me pide reenviar el formulario.......
2. Si hago una respuesta y abandono la pagina y luego vuelvo a esa pregunta id ya no estan las respuestas
3. Me muestra respuestas solo cuando reenvio respuestas.....

[image: Aqui estoy por enviar la respuesta]

[image: Aqui ya he enviado la respuesta]

Si yo abandono esa pagina y vuelvo la respuesta ya no esta, y se vuelve a mostrar solo cuando vuelvo a responder esa pregunta, y si me vuelvo a salir la historia se repite.

Espero puedan ayudarme crack
Saludos

Comment: Es necesario que muestres el código PHP encargado de hacer todo lo que comentas. En cuanto a que al actualizar te pregunta si querés reenviar los datos, se debe a que estás usando la misma URL para ver el formulario y para enviarlo. Deberías usar 2 distintas y luego de enviar la información, redireccionar a la primera.

Comment: Hola azeos, espero puedas ayudarme. Añadire mas codigo.